# программа вылетает(c++,qt)

Tags: c++, qt, файлы, fstream

У меня все файлы находятся в папке build-****-Desktop_Qt_5_11_1_MSVC2017_64bit-Release.Считываю файлы в вектор в слоте кнопки.что Не так?

Переменные и заголовки:

```
std::vector<int>VecAnswers;
std::vector<std::string>VecQuestions;

std::vector<Var>VecVariants;
Var radioBut;

std::ifstream finQu("Qu.txt");
std::ifstream finVar("Var.txt");
std::ifstream finAns("Ans.txt");
```

А вот не рабочее место:

```
finAns>>k;
//qDebug()<<k<<endl;
VecAnswers.reserve(k);
//qDebug()<<VecAnswers.capacity()<<endl;
//qDebug()<<VecAnswers.size()<<endl;
VecVariants.reserve(k);
//qDebug()<<VecVariants.size()<<endl;
VecQuestions.reserve(k);
//qDebug()<<VecQuestions.size()<<endl;
for (int i = 0; i < k; ++i) {
    finAns>>VecAnswers[i];

    std::getline(finVar,VecVariants[i].s1);
    std::getline(finVar,VecVariants[i].s2);
    std::getline(finVar,VecVariants[i].s3);

    std::getline(finQu,VecQuestions[i]);
}
```

push_back'ом еще не пробовал.

Comment: `reserve` выделяет память под будущие вставки элементов в вектор, он не увеличивает количество элементов в векторе. Вместо него нужно использовать `resize`, ну или `reserve` + `push_back`

Answer (score -1):

С push_back все работает:

```
int Ans;
Var Vari;
std::string Quest;
finAns>>k;
//qDebug()<<k<<endl;
//VecAnswers.reserve(k);
//qDebug()<<VecAnswers.capacity()<<endl;
//qDebug()<<VecAnswers.size()<<endl;
//VecVariants.reserve(k);
//qDebug()<<VecVariants.size()<<endl;
//VecQuestions.reserve(k);
//qDebug()<<VecQuestions.size()<<endl;
for (int i = 0; i < k; ++i) {
    finAns>>Ans;
    VecAnswers.push_back(Ans);

    std::getline(finVar,Vari.s1);
    std::getline(finVar,Vari.s2);
    std::getline(finVar,Vari.s3);

    VecVariants.push_back(Vari);

    std::getline(finQu,Quest);

    VecQuestions.push_back(Quest);
}
```

Но что не так было?

Comment: Скорее всего это связано с тем, что вы использовали reserve, а не resize

Comment: Отредактируйте вопрос и вставте обновление туда, а не пишите в ответ